# Is there a way to change a label text from within a UIPageViewController while staying on same page?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I currently have a UIPageViewController and I need it to change text once a completion block finishes while staying on the same page. I tried doing it this way:

```
   func addChainedAnimationView (titleLabel: String, descriptionLabel: String){
//
(completion: {(finished) in
   DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                            self.label1?.text = titleLabel

                        }
        })
}
```

but I get an error

> EXC_ BAD_ INSTRUCTION

This is how the view controllers are built, it's shortened so you can disregard some of the parameters:

```
public class WelcomePageView : UIView
{
    public var animationStrings : [String]?
    public var titleStrings: [String]?
    public var descriptionStrings: [String]?

    var index: Int = 0
}

  var label1 : UILabel?
    var label2 : UILabel?

    func buildViewControllerWithImage(titleString : String, titleString2 : String?, descriptionString: String, descriptionString2: String?, backgroundImage: String, jsonFile : String, jsonFile2 : String?, index : Int, loopCount: Int, userType: User, isLottieChained: Bool) -> UIViewController
    {

     let vc : UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "WelcomePageView", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))
        (vc.view as? WelcomePageView)!.index = index
        vc.view.frame = self.view.frame
         var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

  var label1String = titleString
        if(!(label1String.contains("\n"))) {
            label1String = "\n"+label1String
        }
        paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
        paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 24
        label1  = (vc.view.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel)!
        label1?.font = UIFont.CustomBold(size: 20)

        var attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: label1String)
        attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
        (vc.view.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel)!.attributedText = attrString
      return vc
    }
```

I get them this way:

```
  func getViewControllerWithImage(_ index: Int, userType: User, country: Country) -> UIViewController

    {
           vc =  self.buildViewControllerWithImage(titleString:"FIRST_SCREEN_TITLE".localized, titleString2: nil, descriptionString: "FIRST_SCREEN_DESCRIPTION".localized, descriptionString2: nil, backgroundImage: "fractal_blue", jsonFile: "Welcome_Step_01_V01", jsonFile2: nil, index: index, loopCount: loopCount, userType: userType, isLottieChained: false)

 return vc
    }
```

They are called here:

```
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index : Int = (viewController.view as? WelcomePageView)!.index // currentIndex = index

//currentIndex = index
//(viewController.view as? WelcomePageView)!.index

print ("XXXXX after \(index) XXXXXXX ")
//index = self.currentIndex
index += 1

if (index == maxPages)
{
    index = 0
}
return self.getViewControllerWithImage(index, userType: User.newUser, country: 

checkCountry())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue may be calling `sync` instead of `async` on DispatchQueue.main.

You are already on the main queue, so you should never call sync, since it will cause a deadlock with the main queue waiting on itself.